# Turn off debug menu on React Native Android apk Release

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I'm on RN 0.26 building an apk like so

```
 cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

and with all the keystore things in place I get a generated `app-release.apk` however the app is still in debug mode when I install it on a device. I get errors and rage menu.

I tried hard coding the `app/react.grade` to

```
def devEnabled = false
```

no luck. This didn't used to happen but I used to be on RN 0.13.

Comment: Strange. Probably you must have tried all these. Just listing. Clean build ? react-native upgrade ? Fresh install on device ?

Comment: I've installed on 5 different devices fresh about 5 different times. Same. I never do react-native upgrade. Breaks everything. Is that a hunch or is there a reason this would fix it?

Comment: Lots of native bridging code, gradle build files has been changed from 0.13 to 0.26. It is expected to perform react-native upgrade. Lots of things could be a mismatch between javascript and native bridge. Have you tried a new project from scratch and built a release version? Does it show up dev errors etc ?

Comment: @agent_hunt, thanks, react-native upgrade didn't solve it but diffing on what it created in my MainActivity.java file allowed me to see that I had getUseDeveloperSupport set to return true. Still don't understand why upgrade doesn't allow for merging, if I override I have to re add all my packages. Does rnpm solve this somehow?

Comment: Yeah. kind of. unless you havent added any native code. You could just overwrite everything while react-native upgrade and do an rnpm link. rnpm is used to easily link(adding projects in build.gradle, linking libraries in xcode etc).  native code for modules.  It has been integrated into react-native-cli. Some modules may not be compliant with rnpm  requirements though.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing this before you generate release apk

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```